# Where to place the standalone JSR223 samplers in between HTTP posts inside a while controller

Tags: jmeter

I have the while controller (as long as a flag is false) which has multiple IFs like:
[image]
I need to set the flag  once certain conditions are satisfied at various places. Where do I need to place the stand alone JSR223 sampler to reset the flag? The locations I have placed it as highlighted is throwing error ('Method getCookieManager() not found in class...' ) as my JSR223 sampler doesn't have an instance of the HTTP Cookie Manager because I have brought the cookies from the one-off setUp thread group to main thread group (payment - via BS PreProcessor).

Answer (score 0):

1. If you're using Beanshell PreProcessor and Beanshell PostProcessor for passing [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) between setup and "normal" thread groups - you need to change **their** location, to wit:

   - Put Beanshell PostProcessor **as a child** of the `02 LOGIN` sampler
   - Put Beanshell PreProcessor **as a child** of the `04 GET PAYT` sampler

     as soon as you do this all `getCookieManager() not found in class` errors will go away
2. Consider migrating from the Beanshell Pre and PostProcessor to the JSR223 equivalents as they may become performance bottleneck when it comes to high loads, see [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for more details

Comment: Dmitri, This error has gone away but when I executed with 2 users, same session id appears in the GET PAYT request. Beanshell PreProcessor has only the below 2 lines:  CookieManager manager = sampler.getCookieManager();
manager.add(props.get("MySessionCookie"));

Comment: You're using the same property, as per [documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html): `Properties are not the same as variables. Variables are local to a thread; properties are common to all threads`. You need to add current thread number to the property so each user could have its own cookie. Passing cookies between thread groups is not something you should be doing as [virtual user is not only about the cookies](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733719-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser-How-to-make-JMeter-behave-more-like-a-real-browser)

Comment: so whats the best way to achieve this, if 'Passing cookies between thread groups is not something you should be doing'? Requirements is like: 100 users and each user should be doing 15 iterations.

Comment: You're overengineering. Just a [Loop Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) with 15 iterations after the login should do the trick for you. If your scenario is more complex consider using [Once Only Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Once_Only_Controller) or [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/six-tips-for-jmeter-if-controller-usage/) so each user would log in only once and set 15 loops on [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) level